# id() function and is operator in python

Tags: python

```
id(5) is id(5)  #returned False
id(5) == id(5)  #returned True
```

is operator returns true if the operands points the same object. Here it is pointing to the same object (i.e., 5). But here, it is returned as False. What's the reason behind that?

Comment: Because you're not comparing 5, you're comparing *the ID of 5*.

Comment: Try doing `print(type(id(5)))`. I will give you a hint: the ID itself is just an int. And for that you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, CPython caches small `int` values, so the same object is always used for `5`.

`id(5)`, however, returns a *large* `int` value (e.g., `id(5) == 4431761200`). This value is *not* cached, so it's possible that two calls to `id(5)` may or may not produce the same *object* representing that value. In the expressions `id(5) is id(5)` and `id(5) == id(5)`, if the large object isn't cached, there are necessarily two distinct objects, because both objects have to be live until `is` or `==` completes its comparison.

Note that in some situations, it might *look* like an object is cached, for example,

```
>>> id(id(5))
4434162352
>>> id(id(5))
4434162352
```

But this is just a case where the same identifier is being reused for two objects whose lifetimes don't overlap.

```
>>> x = id(5)
>>> y = id(5)
>>> x == y
True
>>> id(x) is id(y)
False
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```